# Shortcut to create interface implementations in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, interface

I'd like to have a shortcut to create an implementation of an interface. Example: right click on an interface file, choose "implement", insert class name. Is there something like this in NetBeans (6.8)?

Comment: you might want to file this as an RFE with the NB project...

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure about Netbeans 6.8 but Netbeans 7.2.1 has this.  Go to the interface and click on the lightbulb and there is an option to "Implement Interface".  Clicking that will launch the dialog where you can specify the class name and the package.

Answer (score 9):

There is not that i know of, any function exactly like you want.

Have you tried using <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>ins</kbd> and choose "Implement method", this allows you to select the methods to implement.

Or click the lightbulb on the class definition line and choose "Implement all methods"

Answer (score 3):

Use  Alt + Enter and you will see the menu for implement all methods